# $on only getting called on one controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a `controller` that has an event called `changeSafe`. I want other controllers to listen when this event gets fired

```
secure.controller('wrapperCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, storeFactory, safeFactory) {    
    $scope.changeSafe = function (safeId) {
        $scope.loading = true;
        safeFactory.setSafe(safeId).then(function (safeData) {
            $scope.safe = safeData;
            $scope.loading = false;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('changeSafe', safeData);
        });
    }
});
```

The first page that loads is called `dashboard` when I add what is below the page re-draws with $scope.safe as I would expect it to.

```
secure.controller('dashboardCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, storeFactory, safeFactory) {    
    $scope.$on('changeSafe', function (event, arg) {        
        bindSafe(arg.safeId);
    }); 
});
```

I have pretty much the exact same thing on my history Controller

```
secure.controller('historyCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, storeFactory, safeFactory) {
    $scope.$on('changeSafe', function (event, arg) {        
       bindHistory(arg.safeId);
    }); 
});
```

Here is I have in the `config` section

```
secure.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/history', {
            templateUrl: '/Angular/History/history.html',
            controller: 'historyCtrl'
        })
    .otherwise({
        templateUrl: '/Angular/Dashboard/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
    });
}]);
```

Whenever I click the button that is held within `wrapperCtrl` only the `$scope.$on` fires in the `dashboardCtrl`. Can anyone see why the `$scope.$on` is not being fired from the `historyCtrl` controller? I'm also unclear why it gets called from `dashboardCtrl` when I'm not on that view anymore.

*When I step through the code, I'm actually seeing the `$rootScope.$on('changeSafe')` getting called multiple times both on history page and dashboard page. I can't figure out why it is changing views back to the dashboard though*

Comment: it could be that the `historyCtrl` is not a descendant of `wrapperCtrl`

Comment: I have a typical `ng-view` inside the markup that `wrapperCtrl` is listed. In my my `config` I tell it when on `/history` that the controller is `historyCtrl`

Comment: _I'm also unclear why it gets called from dashboardCtrl when I'm not on that view anymore_ : you need to unregister the event listeners set on $rootScope (those on $scope are unregistered automatically). Otherwise the controllers are kept alive and when undesired, this is a memory leak.

Comment: is it best to kill them when it goes to the separate view?

Comment: Sorry I just see you broadcast on $rootScope, but listen on $scope (did not note the difference before). In this case you shouldn't need to unregister it (though it wouldn't hurt either). The issue may lie within your bindSafe function ?

Comment: By the way, your $rootScope dependency injections are never used in both history and dashboard controllers. That's what confused me :)

Comment: could you paste more code here, like html code, or create a fiddle for your code.

Comment: Yes, I'll add some more code. Also when I click the button that triggers the `chageSafe` the route changes back to my default `dashboard` view

Comment: You're not injecting `$scope` into the historyCtrl, only `$rootScope`.  What happens if you inject `$scope`?

Comment: actually I am along with a few other things, I removed it on accident when creating this

Comment: I found the answer. On my `<a>` tag there was a stray `href=#_` which is why the route was changing. I would still like to know why the `changeSafe` is called multiple times

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I have a full grasp of your problem, but my best guess is you are having a load order issue and the event is being broadcasted before the subscription has been initialized.

---

First off, to save yourself a lot of headaches, it is important to have a solid understanding of [Event Handling in AnguarJS](http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/):

- know the difference between subscribing on $rootScope.$on vs
  $scope.$on
- know the difference of publishing with $broadcast vs $emit on
  $rootScope vs $scope

From the comments it sounds like you might have been using $rootScope.$on, which isn't cleaned up when your controllers are destroyed (same as directives):

```
var changeSafeListnerUnbindFunction = $rootScope.$on('changeSafe', funciton() { //... });

$scope.$on('$destroy', changeSafeListnerUnbindFunction);
```

Given your use case, registering listeners on the child scopes will pick up events published from the $rootScope.$broadcast (which communicates top level down to each child scope). 
You probably have a load order issue?

Comment: I found the answer. On my <a> tag there was a stray href=#_ which is why the route was changing. I will review the event handling link you sent though, I need a better grasp on that

Comment: That would make sense, because then the controller would not be initialized